# To decrypt, first compute: a’ = a^(P−1−x) (mod P); How can I use javascript to compute the a'?

Tags: javascript, security, encryption

I'm tring to use javascript to compute a’ = a^(P−1−x) (mod P), the code is

> var a1 = Math.pow(a, (p-1-x))%p

the console shows a1 is NaN, Can you help? More thanks!

Comment: What are `a`, `p`, `x` and `p`? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Btw, don't write crypto stuff yourself, use a library instead. And JavaScript operates on floating point numbers, not large integers..

Comment: Almost certainly, you want to use [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) for all those values. You'll  want to use a different implementation of BigInts than I linked to, one that implements a modular exponentiation method. Also note that the particular thing you are computing may be better done by a combination of other methods include use of the extended euclidean algorithm.